# Why does delete a sheet cause my code to stop

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code here (Below) I need to clear the data within the WorkSheet "Data Entry" there may be other, quicker, ways to do this, but i went with delete and remake. Please feel free to say if so.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim DataEntryWs As Worksheet

For i = Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1

If Worksheets(i).Name = "Data Entry" Then

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Data Entry").Delete
    MsgBox ("Sheet Deleted")
    Set DataEntryWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    DataEntryWs.Name = "Data Entry"
    Call Data_Entry_Calcs

Else

    If i = Worksheets.Count Then

        MsgBox ("Adding new sheets now")
        Set DataEntryWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        DataEntryWs.Name = "Data Entry"
        Call Data_Entry_Calcs

    Else

    End If

End If

Next i

Call Data_Entry_Calcs

End Sub
```

Whenever I run the code, if the Sheet named "Data Entry" is present then when the code gets to this line `Worksheets("Data Entry").Delete` the code breaks and dosen't contiue. Why is this the case? Been annoying me for a while now.

I have tried running the `For` loop both forwards and backwards to see if this has made any difference, but had no success with it.

Comment: If the sheet already exists then you could do `Worksheets("Data Entry").UsedRange.Clear` without running a loop.

Comment: Is it the only sheet when you are trying to delete it? (Your code works for me). What is the error?

Comment: @JpadLimited there are about 20-30 sheets in the WorkBook, the code works expect when deleteing the sheet call `"Data Entry" ` at this point it wont display the message box, the code just stop.

Comment: @JpadLimited do you get the msgbox saying "Sheet Deleted"?

Comment: This can occur is the button you are using to initiate your Macro is on the sheet that is being deleted. Do you have a button on the sheet being deleted? You may want to read this previous question for more context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896369/deleting-sheet-with-vba-crashes-excel

Comment: @Petrichor no the button is from a UserForm seperate to that sheet

Comment: There is a different delete approach quoted on the above question's answers, might be worth a try after altering to your needs: (<> represents new line). 
`Dim graphSheet As Chart <>
For Each graphSheet in this Workbook.Charts <>
graphSheet.Delete <>
Next graphSheet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about clearing the contents of that Sheet instead of deleting it, such as:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim DataEntryWs As Worksheet

For i = Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Data Entry" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets("Data Entry").Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents 'clear the contents from Row 2 to last
        Call Data_Entry_Calcs
    Else
        If i = Worksheets.Count Then
            MsgBox ("Adding new sheets now")
            Set DataEntryWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
            DataEntryWs.Name = "Data Entry"
            Call Data_Entry_Calcs
        End If
    End If
Next i

Call Data_Entry_Calcs

End Sub
```

Comment: This works well baring 1 minor issues. 1) - It dosn't see, to clear any data in Column A

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this instead. You don't need the loop to do this if I understand what you're trying to do correctly

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim DataEntryWs As Worksheet

    ' Set Sheet want to test to variable
    ' We use error handling in case it doesn't exist. If it doesn't exists DataEntryWs = nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set DataEntryWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry")
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Test if sheet exists. If does Delete
    If Not DataEntryWs Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        DataEntryWs.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        MsgBox "Sheet Deleted"
    End If

    ' Add new sheet
    MsgBox "Adding new sheets now"
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set DataEntryWs = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With
    DataEntryWs.Name = "Data Entry"

    Call Data_Entry_Calcs
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Thank you for getting back to me, when i run your code, I get the same issue, i.e. Its able to delete the sheet called "Data Entry" but wont add a new one back in. I dont even get as far as the msgbox "Sheet Deleted". When using breakpoint on each line, its works fine until the deleiting line where it seems the code ends. Does that make sense?

Comment: Where are you putting the code? In a module, the sheet? Also where is the command button you're clicking? Which sheet is it in?

Comment: I currently have the code in a new module, the `CommandButton1` is from  a copy and paste from its eventual desitination which is a userform. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code and let me know what happens, and yes, I do get the messagebox when I run it...

```
        Sub Test2()
        Dim i As Integer

            On Error GoTo err_handler

            For i = Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1

                If Worksheets(i).Name = "Data Entry" Then

                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    Worksheets("Data Entry").Delete
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

                    MsgBox ("Sheet Deleted")

                End If

            Next i

            Exit Sub

err_handler:
        MsgBox Err.Description

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try just this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim DataEntryWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set DataEntryWs = Sheets("Data Entry")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not DataEntryWs Is Nothing Then
        DataEntryWs.Cells.Clear
        MsgBox "Sheet Data Entry cleared.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Adding new sheet now.", vbInformation
        With ThisWorkbook
            Set DataEntryWs = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
            DataEntryWs.Name = "Data Entry"
        End With
    End If
    DataEntryWs.Activate
    Call Data_Entry_Calcs
End Sub
```